# Rails best practices / naming schemas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, naming

Hi I'm fairly new to rails and I'm trying to decide how to handle images/media. I have multiple models that would have images. Some with multiple images. I was wondering if there are any foreseeable problems with naming a table/model "images"?

Ultimately I think "media" might be a better solution, as I may want to upload files other than just images, however, that seems like it might cause some confusion pluralization wise e.g.: media_controller vs medias_controller?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about plural and single at all. Rails will keep what it is in natural English.

```
"media".pluralize
#=> "media"
```

Besides, for images, I don't see any problem to use "Image" as model name.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are going to attach files to a model, I'd strongly advise using something like [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle the attachments.  Storing all the media or images in a single table will end up causing performance problems rather quickly.  Paperclip handles saving the media to the filesystem, and allows you to interact with it just as if it's a field in the DB.

Comment: Right, yeah I was going to use Paperclip. I meant naming for the model/table that will keep track of the record.